# Каскадное связывание combobox и enum

Tags: c#, wpf

На входе : два combobox и четыре enum

```
    enum Country
    {
        USA,
        Russia,
        Germany
    }

    enum USA
    {
        Alabama,
        Alaska,
        Arizona,
        Arkansas
    }
    enum Russia
    {
        Adygea,
        Bashkortostan,
        Mordovia
    }
    enum Germany
    {
        Berlin,
        Bremen,
        Hamburg,
        Wiesbaden
    }
```

enum contains a lot of values

На выходе получаем:

1. Визуально,что  в соответствии с выбором страны из первого combobox получаем соответствующий список во втором combobox(каскадное);
2. внутри есть единое свойство со значением региона, которое можно serialize and deserialize.

Проблема в том что непонятно как привести 3 enum к одному типу, либо как-то сделать по другому. Заводить один enum со всеми регионами думаю плохая идея, потому что нужно будет каждому региону устанавливать страну и это очень плохо с огромными enum. Как мне быть ?

Comment: Связывать по названию не очень идея. Почему использовать классы вместо enum не хотите?

Comment: Зачем так жестко хардкодить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю привязываться не к enum, а парсить данные нужным образом во VM, например создать класс `CountryVM` в нем буду города `CityVM`. Далее к одному ComboBox привязывать страны, к другому `SelectedCounrty.Cities`

Comment: Или наоборот, регионы будут иметь ссылку на страну и при смене страны делать where из списка регионов.

Comment: Это, мне кажется, более логичным. В вашем случае один регион может прописаться в несколько стран

Comment: @Андрей, правильность заполнения в данном случае ложится на программиста. А разве по-вашему 2 региона из разных стран, не может прописать ссылку на одну страну?)

Comment: Отношение такое : одна страна - много регионов, конкретному одному региону соответствует одна страна

Comment: т.е. вы предлагаете public class Country
{
  public eCountry Name {
    get;
    set;}
  
  public ICollection<City> Cities {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
  
public class City
{
  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

Comment: @All888, совершенно верно.

Comment: но тогда мне нужно будет для каждой страны прописать в конструкторе, правильно понимаю? и ни как этого не избежать , если у меня 249 стран и для каждой страны тоже не малый список  new Country(){ Name = "USA",
        Cities = new List<City>()
        {
          new City(){ Name = "" },
          new City(){ Name = "" },
          new City(){ Name = "" }
        }}

Comment: @All888, а откуда вы сейчас получаете данные? Можно же написать парсер, необязательно прописывать все города вручную.

Comment: @All888, сформируйте, например, xml-ку и при запуске загружайте из нее. enum на 249 значений и еще 249 enum-ов - это точно жесть

Comment: если брать структуру классов, то все данные прописываю в конструкторе получается, не понимаю что из себя будет представлять парсер ? страны все равно придется все прописывать ?

Comment: дошло , пишу xml структуру в файле и серелизую в класс?

Comment: Десериализауете*. Необязательно данные хранить в xml, можно в какой нибудь БД. затем при создании VM. вытягиваете нужные данные запросом и все. А так да, можно и сделать и так.